# Estimating when it's done in excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, time-estimation

Can I, somehow, based on time stamp and how much is done, estimate time and date for when a job is complete? I got this log that a bot I've made writes in column A time [yyy-mm-dd hh:mm], and in column B it wrights how much is done. It sorts it all with newest on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gary's answer is correct, but for convenience if the 2nd row of data can be an arbitrary progress status (not just start of task = implicitly 0%), and if you use percentage number format (or decimals) and you would like to get the end date instead of just the duration, use following formula:

```
=A1+(A1-A2)/(B1-B2)*(1-B1)
```

[image: formula printscreen]

Comment: Nice, sorta easy, subtle and all in one cell not counting B line! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

[image]

In this example the time span is **1 hour** and the percent complete in the time span is **78%**
Cell **C1** contains:

```
=100-B1
```

the percent remaining to be done.

In cell **D1** is the formula:

```
=(A1-A2)/B1
```

**D1** yields the time required to complete **1%**

Finally in **E1:**

```
=D1*C1
```

the time required to complete the work!
*(Note...**C1,D1,E1** can be combined into a single formula)*

**EDIT#1**

The formats of **E1** and **D1** were picked to display the relevent parts of the data
The format  of **D1,E1** is:   ***mm-dd hh:mm:ss.00***

Change this format to suit your needs!

Comment: `=(A1-A2)/(B1-B2)` if previous status was not 0%?

Comment: Thank you! Running into some issues do not know if it is formating or not. What I know is that B1:C1 is formatted as percent (because it's what it has to be), and D1:E1 is formated to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" but what I get then from D1 is: 1900-01-00 01:16 and E1 is: 1900-01-00 00:16.
I have copied word for word, but it's not working..

Comment: ah... the end date instead of duration would be `=A1 + D1*C1`

Comment: note the task in your sample data is not supposed to take 1 mont to finish, just the 16 minutes 55 seconds part, `[h]:mm:ss` might be a better suitable format for time diff

Comment: @Aprillion ...............you are correct.....I will search for a better format..............